# asp.net update doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to do a update in a formview but it doesn't work. I add a breakpoint at the begin of the update methode, and he goes perfectly trough the whole methode. But a classmate told me that at the end of the methode (after "return i") he has to go to the BO.orders.cs, and he doesn't do that. I don't get any errors. 
Is there somebody who can help me?
(Sorry for my bad english)

This is my update methode and GetConnectionString

```
 public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
          ["BookstoreConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }

public static int UpdateOrder(Order order)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

        string sql = "UPDATE tblOrders " +
          "SET Name = @name, Address = @address, " +
          "City = @city, Pc = @pc, Date = @date, Book_id = @book_id, Count = @count, Amount = @amount, " +
          "Delivered = @delivered, Ddate = @ddate, Paid = @paid, Pdate = @pdate " +
          " WHERE Id = @Id";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", order.OrderId);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", order.Name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", order.Address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", order.City);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pc", order.Pc);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", order.Date);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@book_id", order.Bookid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", order.Count);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", order.Amount);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@delivered", order.Delivered);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paid", order.Paid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ddate", order.Ddate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pdate", order.Pdate);


        conn.Open();
        int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();

        return i;
    }
```

And  this is my objectdatasource of my formview

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="dtsDetail" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="BO.Order" DeleteMethod="DeleteOrder" InsertMethod="InsertOrder" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" SelectMethod="GetOrdersByOrderId" TypeName="DAL.OrdersDAL" UpdateMethod="UpdateOrder">
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Date" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Amount" Type="Decimal" />
    </UpdateParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="gv" Name="ID" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What is "BO.orders.cs"? Does the data get updated in the database?

Comment: may be you implemented it differently than your classmate and don't need to go through BO.Order.cs. Isn't your primary goal to have the order updated in the DB with this code? Did that part succeed? Also what do you expect to happen when the code runs through BO.Order.cs?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler Yes it doesn't has to be the same as my classmate but he doesn't update the orders and that's my problem

Comment: Okay, that is a problem :). Could you set the break point on conn.Close() and examine what is the value of "i" after you've called ExecuteNonQuery()?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler "i" is 0

Comment: That means the number of rows impacted by that sql command is 0, which means no rows were updated. It could be because that there isn't any record with the id that you are passing as a parameter.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to add 'id' in my sql string, cause when I do this I always get a error because he is doing the id automatically (I think)

Comment: @RQDQ  BO.orders.cs is my class where I do all my getters and setters and no the data doesn't update in the database

Comment: No. What I mean is your update sqlScript is looking for a row that has an id of whatever the value of  order.OrderID is (cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", order.OrderId);) and it cannot find a matching row, so it doesn't update anything.

Comment: It works, thank you so much!

Comment: Happy to be of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of "i" is 0 (as mentioned in the comment) after you've called ExecuteNonQuery(), that means 0 rows were updated after executing your sql query.

Basically, your update statement (`string sql = "UPDATE tblOrders "`...) is looking for a row that has an id of whatever the value of `order.OrderID` is (...`" WHERE Id = @Id";` `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", order.OrderId);`) and it cannot find a matching row, so it doesn't update anything. So, to get the update working, you will need to provide an id that exists.